# Sprite is scaling instead of cropping

Tags: html, css, sprite, rollover

I had created these images for a rollover effect and the following code did work. However it has recently broken when I tried adding a modal popup for another button on the site. I've reverted the changes to the code (removed the modal pop-up) but the sprites are still broken. Instead of just showing the light banner, and then the dark on hover, it shows both of the sprite segments and scales them in. What is causing this and how can I stop it from happening?

[image: This is what is happening, it should only show the light banners, and then switch to dark on hover]
[image]

```css
a, img {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

a.rolla {
  display: block;
  width: 200 px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-size: 200px 258px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

a.rollb {
  display: block;
  width: 200 px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-size: 200px 258px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

a.rollc {
  display: block;
  width: 200 px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-size: 200px 258px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

a.rolld {
  display: block;
  width: 200 px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-size: 200px 258px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

a.rollover:hover, a.rollover2:hover, a.rollover3:hover {
  background-position: -213px 0;
}

a.rolla:hover, a.rollb:hover, a.rollc:hover, a.rolld:hover {
  background-position: -210px 0;
}

.displace {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5000px;
}

body {
  background: url("rpt.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#banner {
  z-index: 0;
}

#feTable {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 455px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div width="1024px">
  <img id="banner" src="banner.jpg" height="512 px" width="1024px">
  <table id="feTable" style="width:1024px; left:22px">
    <tr>

      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rollb"><span class="displace"></a>
      </td>

      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rolla"><span class="displace"></a>
      </td>

      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rollc"><span class="displace"></a>
      </td>

      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rolld"><span class="displace"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `background-size: 200px 258px;`. The code example you have provided isn't particularly helpful without the images.

Comment: That stops the image from being squashed, but still shows the part of the hover image. How can I crop that out.Added the banner image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems with your code.

The first is that you are using `background-size: 200px 258px;`. Specifying length values for `background-size` will force the background to those dimensions. This is squashing you 412 x 260 image down to 200 X 258, which is why the entire image is shown.

> `<length>`
>
> A `<length>` value that scales the background image to the specified length in the corresponding dimension. Negative lengths are not allowed.

*background-size (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)*

The second is that you have incorrectly specified the `width` on `a.rolla`, `a.rollb`, `a.rollc` and `a.rolld`. The space between `200` and `px` means it is being ignored and is growing to the width of the containing `td` (which in turn shows more of the background than is required).

To fix, make the following changes:

- Change `width: 200 px;` to `width: 200px;` on `a.rolla`, `a.rollb`, `a.rollc` and `a.rolld`
- Remove `background-size: 200px 258px;` from `a.rolla`, `a.rollb`, `a.rollc` and `a.rolld`

```css
a,
img {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
a.rolla {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
a.rollb {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
a.rollc {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
a.rolld {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 258px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPyD.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
a.rollover:hover,
a.rollover2:hover,
a.rollover3:hover {
  background-position: -213px 0;
}
a.rolla:hover,
a.rollb:hover,
a.rollc:hover,
a.rolld:hover {
  background-position: -210px 0;
}
.displace {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5000px;
}
body {
  background: url("rpt.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#banner {
  z-index: 0;
}
#feTable {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div width="1024px">
  <table id="feTable" style="width:1024px; left:22px">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rollb"><span class="displace"></span></a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rolla"><span class="displace"></span></a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rollc"><span class="displace"></span></a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="200px">
        <a target="_parent" href="" class="rolld"><span class="displace"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. Very informative and sorted out my issues.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.rolla, a.rollb {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```